Could there be an open subset of a scheme which is homeomorphic to an affine scheme but not isomorphic as schemes?
Let $X$ be a scheme, and $U\subset X$ an open subset such that as topological spaces we have a homeomorphism $U\cong \operatorname{Spec}A$ for some ring $A$. Does it follow that $U\cong \operatorname{Spec}A$ as schemes as well? I.e. if $f:U\subset X\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}A$ is the homeomorphism, is there a sheaf isomorphism $\mathscr{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A}\rightarrow f_*(\mathscr{O}_X|_U)$?
I feel like the answer should probably be yes, but I can't think of a good reason why.
I am asking this question because I am trying to prove that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a closed embedding of schemes (i.e. $f$ is a homeomorphism onto a closed subset of $Y$, and $f^\sharp:\mathscr{O}_Y\rightarrow f_*\mathscr{O}_X$ is a surjection) then every affine open $U=\operatorname{Spec}A\subset Y$ satisfies $f^{-1}(U)\cong \operatorname{Spec}A/I$ for some ideal $I\subset A$. I have been able to show that $f^{-1}(U)$ is homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec}A/I$ rather easily, but showing that they are isomorphic as schemes as been harder.

Great instinct to try to attack from the topological angle; unfortunately, this is very far from true, the topology tells you more-or-less nothing. For another example, the affine line is homeomorphic to the affine line minus any finite number of closed points, but none of these schemes is isomorphic to one another.

@hunter Thank you I now see the flaw in this approach

If $K$ and $L$ are non-isomorphic fields, then $\operatorname{Spec} K$ is homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec} L$, but the two schemes are not isomorphic.

Somewhat more relevant to your problem is the following observation: Given a ring $A$ and an ideal $I\subset A$, the subschemes $\operatorname{Spec} A/I$ and $\operatorname{Spec} A / I^k$ have the same topological space for each $k\in \mathbb N$.
